# Which endpoint will reveal the Outlook email address using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

After OAuth and receiving the access token, I'm able to query the endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` to get the owner details. However, the email address returned in the response is the email address attached to the resource owner (userPrincipalName), not necessarily the email address of the owner's outlook account. For example, if I then hit the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages` endpoint, I can see the "from" email address is the email address that I actually want (in the Sent folder), or the "to" address in other folders, but the owner details email address (userPrincipalName) is different. The userPrincipalName is the sign-in email address, but in this case, the Outlook email address is a different email address. My question: is there an endpoint where I can get the email address (or addresses) used in Outlook rather than the email address of the owner?

Comment: Have you take a look at the results for the user in the people resource collection?
/me/people/{userId} might be helpful

Comment: Thanks @GavinB ... tried it but it didn't give me the information for which I'm looking. I've updated the question above to add a bit more clarification. In short, the _login_ (userPrincipalName) email address is different than the user's Outlook email address, I need the Outlook email address even if there are zero email messages available for me to scan.

Comment: Hmm, this describes my corporate account perfectly my primary mail alias is different to my upn. 
On the `/me` result object there are two properties `upn` and `email` these correctly match what I expect on my profile first.last@corpdomain.com and first.last@subsidarydomain.com in my case

Comment: Totally... an in most cases this will be correct. But in this edge case where 1) the user has a non-Microsoft email address they have associated with their Microsoft account and 2) they have a _different_ email address they use with Outlook and 3) they have zero messages in any folder... it seems like it's impossible to find out their Outlook email address. :/

Comment: Oh, so like creating an MSA for a gmail account then?